# token based authentication web api

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, token

I am developing a Xamarin app, and a web API (web service) to connect my app with sql server db. I have a table for storing user credentials in my existing db, and now i want to implement token based authentication, so the user puts username and password in the client xamarin app and the web API generates a token for this user if the credentials exists in this db, so use can access this API by this token. Can this db be used for validating user credentials or there is a new db (identity) the is created for this purpose? am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: try to search before asking question. have a look at this article [Web api token Authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

Comment: @esiprogrammer i did it buddy, i did token authentication with a new db created for storing token..but i want to use mt own db for validantion the existing users usernames and passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use numbers of ways, my favorite is Mixing JWT/OAuth and ASP.NET Identity 2.1, here is an [example](https://github.com/OdeToCode/ngplaybook). 
And of course esiprogrammer's Article is very handy, here is another [example](https://github.com/tjoudeh/WebApiHMACAuthentication) on that.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos apologies i do not have enough rep to comment :)

Comment: There is a reason for that rule. An answer should actually answer a question. Comments are for discussion.

Comment: i have existing db with 200 users, can i validate users from there or i have to register users form the beginning in a new db (membership db or something like this) ?

Comment: @user2466059 basically for token authentication, you need to add Token and ExpirationDate to the columns of your User Table. Whenever a user wants to login, a token is generated by any of examples above will be stored in that field, and is identified by it, then you need to check if that token is expired or not if so user need to make another login, thats the basics. you can check the both projects see which one is more suitable for your work.